# ADO.NET: Do you need to Rollback a transaction?

Tags: c#, transactions

Consider the following code which does not rollback the transaction if an exception is caught.

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
command.Transaction = transaction;
try {
    // interact with database here
catch {}
finally {
    connection.Close();
}
```

What are the consequences of this and is it necessary to rollback the transaction?

Comment: Try it - cause an exception and see the results.  Your error reported will be about the transaction not being rolled back and this will hide whatever exception was actually thrown.

Comment: @Paddy: Are you saying an exception will be thrown about the transaction not being rolled back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will leave an open transaction on the database, which could potential block other queries.

Taken from [here](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ADO.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Transactions):

> Consider the following general
> guidelines when you use transactions
> so that you can avoid causing
> deadlocks:
>
> - Always access tables in the same order
>   across transactions in your
>   application. The likelihood of a
>   deadlock increases when you access
>   tables in a different order each time
>   you access them.
> - Keep transactions as
>   short as possible. Do not make
>   blocking or long-running calls from a
>   transaction. Keep the duration of the
>   transactions short. One approach is to
>   run transactions close to the data
>   source. For example, run a transaction
>   from a stored procedure instead of
>   running the transaction from a
>   different computer.
> - Choose a level of
>   isolation that balances concurrency
>   and data integrity. The highest
>   isolation level, serializable, reduces
>   concurrency and provides the highest
>   level of data integrity. The lowest
>   isolation level, read uncommitted,
>   gives the opposite result.

Comment: +1. This is a potentially long transactio nthere until the GC kicks in, keeping all locks around. Can be devastating to the performance.

Comment: The transaction ends when the connection is closed without committing. I don't understand why this was accepted. A transaction requires a connection. If the connection is gone, so is the tran.

Answer (score 16):

The best is to generate your transaction inside a using block like this:

```
using( /*code to create the transaction you want )
{
  //perform your transaction here
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

If you code fails before the call to commit, it will automatically be rolled back as the using block is exited.